# Create a single list of values from from a list of dictionary using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionary as below:
`name_list = [{'a':['alice', 'bob']},{'a':[]},{'a':['sam','alex']}, {'a':[]}]`

I want a final list as below using python list comprehension:
`['alice', 'bob', 'sam', 'alex']`

I tried doing
`for name in name_list:` 
   `final_list = [value for key,value in name.items() if len(value)>0]`

Can someone please help me

Comment: I still can't understand how you have assigned the same key to different values in a dictionary, Either try using default dict to assign keys :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
final_list = [name for name_dict in name_list for name in name_dict["a"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_list = [{'a':['alice', 'bob']},{'a':[]},{'a':['sam','alex']}, {'a':[]}]

my_list = [i for x in name_list for i in x['a']]
```

here is your list comprehension. so your list will be equal to i for x in name list for i in x['a']

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It's an example of list comprehension.

```
[l for i in name_list for j, k in i.items() for l in k if len(k)>0]
```